# In Sveltekit we can access FormData on they body. But how to create FormData in unit-test?

Tags: sveltekit

I'm trying to unit test a function that expect's a `FormData` type as described in `'@sveltejs/kit/types/helper'`.

My question is, how can I create such a `FormData` type when unit-testing the function?

I tried using the npm `form-data` package, but did not work as `.entries()` was missing (and the interface was also completely different).